# how to see the styles applied during hover of an element in ie

Tags: css

Is there any way to view the styles applied during hovering of an element in Internet Explorer? Chrome and Firefox provide this in styles tab as we can see in console bar.

I want to know whether the same thing can be viewed in Internet Explorer. If so how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you've pressed F12 and selected the element in question, you will be shown the CSS styles on the right - this does not however update when you hover over the element like in FireBug - nor can you set it's state as ':hover'. What you can do, is once the element is selected, ensure the focus is on the developer bar and hover over the element on the page - while hovered over it, press `F5` - if you now reselect that element, the styles on the right hand side will show you the `:hover` styles ("Trace Styles" will also update)

Answer (score 2):

In IE, you just press F12 and it will bring up the Developer Console. There you will find a CSS Tab.
Or after bringing up the Developer Console ( F12 ) you can use the pointer tool to highlight an element on your page and you will view the element Styles on the right pane of the Developer Console

http://www.sitepoint.com/debug-faster-with-f12-developer-tools-in-internet-explorer-9/

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to,

Tools >> DeveloperTools

Shotcut- F12

Answer (score 0):

**go to InternetExplorer menu : ->Tools->Developer Tools Shortcut : f12**